# How to create a unique property in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In azure table storage is it possible to add a unique constraint on a column of a given table?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Table Storage entities don't have *columns*. Each entity may have *properties* and these properties don't need to be the same for each entity.

The only unique constraint is the combination of `partition key` + `row key`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent article on Azure table storage here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx

Since it only has a Row Key and a Partition Key, and the Row Key is essentially the primary key, it doesn't look like there's any other constraint you can put on it unless you build that sort of thing into your client/server which uses or exposes it.

From the article:

> The Table service does not enforce any schema for tables, so two entities in the same table may have different sets of properties. Developers may choose to enforce a schema on the client side. A table may contain any number of entities.

HTH :)